# Can SolrNet Support Json

Tags: json, solr, solrnet

I want solr response the json data.So Can SolrNet can receive the json data and do analysis just like serialization?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. IMHO there is no reason to implement this. See for discussion and rationale:

- http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=106
- http://groups.google.com/group/solrnet/browse_thread/thread/2793f29c12fc75ac

Answer (score 0):

Just to add from my own experience as JSON is a requirement over XML in my current Solr + SolrNet project. Whatever SolrNet does internally doesn't make a difference IMHO if it is done magically + fast and I get my result in a nice POCO object.

That was my position when my team architect told me that we can't use SolrNet because it uses XML internally. I explained how he was not looking at the big picture because implementing everything manually from scratch just to use JSON internally is like reinventing the wheel.

It is not as simple as setting up a few calls via RESTSharp and parsing via Json.NET.